# Eloquent whereDate clause using date value as a column

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-carbon

I'm trying to update all records where the date today is less than 30 days before the record was created + a duration value. For example

Today is less than created_at + 50 (days) - 30 day notification period.

```
$subscriptions = Order::whereNotNull('service_id')->with('service')->get();

foreach($subscriptions as $subscription){
    Order::where('id', $subscription->id)
    ->where(Carbon::today(), '<', Carbon::parse($subscription->created_at)->addDays($subscription->service->duration)->subDays(30))
    ->update(['status_id' => 7]);
}
```

The error I get is;

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2020-08-21 00:00:00' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `orders` set `status_id` = 7
, `orders`.`updated_at` = 2020-08-21 21:01:58 where `id` = 3 and date(`2020-08-21 00:00:00`) < 2021-01-13)
```

Comment: You need to specify the column when calling `whereDate`. Try `->whereDate('created_at', ... `.

Comment: Then I have to use 'where' in this situation as I don't want to compare a column value?

Comment: No, just add the date column's name as the first parameter: `whereDate('created_at', '<', '2020-08-21 00:00:00')`.

Comment: I'm not comparing a date column in my query?

Comment: No you're not as it's written. Adding the column as the first parameter will fix that.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter This won't work, you can't append to a column name in an Eloquent `where` clause. The question is not trying to compare specifically the 'created_at' column

Comment: @archvist He specifically says "Today is less than created_at + 50 (days) - 30 day notification period.", so yes, he is comparing the `created_at` column. I don't follow what you mean by " you can't append to a column name in an Eloquent where clause" etiher.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Yes, `+ 50 (days) - 30 day` which you can't append to a column name as stated. You're more than welcome to submit an answer to the question if you believe you have something that will work.

Comment: @archvist He means the value of the created_at column then add 50 days then subtract 30. Besides, `+` is not the concat operator in PHP, so where are getting appending to the name from? If you read the entire question, you'll see: `Carbon::parse($subscription->created_at)->addDays($subscription->service->duration)->subDays(30)`, which is what I've been saying.

Answer (score 0):

The foreach seem not relevant as per the given problem.

Then here is a `whereRaw()` way to achieve it in a single update but functions (DATEDIFF, CURDATE) may differ from a DB engine to an other, here is the MySQL variant:

```
Order::whereNotNull('service_id')
    ->with('service')
    ->whereRaw('DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `order`.`created_at`) < `service`.`duration` - 30')
    ->update(['status_id' => 7]);
```

Else you can do it updating 1 order at a time using pure PHP statements instead of where clauses:

```
foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    if (Carbon::parse($subscription->created_at)->addDays($subscription->service->duration)->subDays(30) < Carbon::today()) {
        $subscription->status_id = 7;
        $subscription->save();
    }
}
```